# How to hide view model (weapon) in Natural Selection 2?

Tags: natural-selection-2

Is there some console command to hide view model, a weapon that is drawn in first person view. Can be a cheat command. I just need it to do some screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join Spectators team. Then in console type:

```
cheats 1
r_gui false
```

To enable gui type:

```
r_gui true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `r_gui 0` to disable the GUI.
Additionally, there's two workshop items that turn the first person weapons invisible:

[Hide Yo Alien Weapons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=109612788)
[Hide Yo Gun Model](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=108114415)

As far as I'm aware it's not possible to do what you want through the console.